Dots connected with lines in cells of a LaTeX table (flowchart)
In my current work I need to prepare a table (called "technological flowchart") in which cells need to contain dots (see the picture below, sorry for the Hungarian language), and the certain dots need to connected with lines (corresponding to the work processes need to carry out on certain pieces one after another). Is this possible to create in LaTeX? Can someone offer me some package or sample code which is capable for my task?
Thank you! 

Here is an example of what you can do with {NiceTabular} of nicematri.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW = north-west
\RowStyle{\rotate}
      & one & two & three \; & four & five \\
one   & \textbullet & \textbullet &             & \textbullet & \textbullet\\
two   & \textbullet & \textbullet & \textbullet & \textbullet & \textbullet\\
three & \textbullet & \textbullet &             & \textbullet & \textbullet\\
four  & \textbullet & \textbullet &             & \textbullet & \textbullet\\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw (2-2) -- (2-3) -- (3-4) -- (2-5) -- (2-6) ; 
  \draw (3-2) -- (3-3) -- (3-4) -- (3-5) -- (3-6) ; 
  \draw (4-2) -- (4-3) -- (3-4) -- (4-5) -- (4-6) ; 
  \draw (5-2) -- (5-3) -- (3-4) -- (5-5) -- (5-6) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

You need several compilations.


That works pretty well, thank you!
